# How to replace comma with semi colon for inner html or text

Tags: javascript

I have below html:

```
<span class="myclass"><a href='javascript:$s("P3_MGR","7839","KING");'>KING</a>, <a href='javascript:$s("P3_MGR","7902","FORD");'>FORD</a>, <a href='javascript:$s("P3_MGR","7566","JONES");'>JONES</a></span>
```

I would like to know how can I replace comma (,) with semi colon(;) that's appearing after closing anchor tag

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: What does `$s()` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: sorry but how would I know its duplication before posting question? I did search before posting but no results were similar to what I want.

Comment: why negative vote for question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest working, but ugly way:

```
document.querySelector('.myclass').innerHTML =  document.querySelector('.myclass').innerHTML.replace(/<\/a>,/g, '</a>;');
```

Nicer way, though still ugly:

```
var toReplace = document.querySelector('.myclass');
toReplace.innerHTML = toReplace.innerHTML.replace(/<\/a>,/g, '</a>;');
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way with [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and `String.replace()` function:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span.myclass');
span.textContent = span.textContent.replace(/,/g, ';');
```

```html
<span class="myclass"><a href='javascript:$s("P3_MGR","7839","KING");'>KING</a>, <a href='javascript:$s("P3_MGR","7902","FORD");'>FORD</a>, <a href='javascript:$s("P3_MGR","7566","JONES");'>JONES</a></span>
```